# Is it necessary to close database connections?

Tags: rethinkdb

[using the JavaScript driver]

I've seen on several of the `rethinkdb` example projects that connections are closed at the end of each query (e.g., `conn.close()`)

While I understand the pedagogical reasons to include that in the tutorials, is it actually performant to manually close connections? I am under the impression that the connection will automatically close once it is out-of-scope

Answer (score 1):

You should not leave connections open..

You should:

1) Open connections as late as possible

2) Close connections as soon as possible

The connection itself is returned to the connection pool. Connections are a limited and relatively expensive resource. Any new connection you establish that has exactly the same connection string will be able to reuse the connection from the pool.